# Display all available tags in aem

Tags: java, jsp, tags, aem

I am trying to make a component that prints all available tags in crx but I am getting a null pointer exception. I created the following interface

```js
package com.aem.community.core.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public interface ListTags {
 Map listAllTags(); 
}
```

and the implemenataion

```js
package com.aem.community.core.services.Impl;

import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.NodeIterator;
import javax.jcr.Session;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.aem.community.core.services.ListTags;
import com.aem.community.core.services.SearchService;
import com.day.cq.tagging.Tag;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Service  
public class ListTagsImpl implements ListTags {
  protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
  
  private Session session;
  
  @Reference
  private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;
  
  @Override
  public Map listAllTags() {
    try { 
      Map<String, String> myHashMap = null;
      Resource tagResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/etc/tags");

      if (tagResource!= null) {
        Iterable<Resource> children = tagResource.getChildren();
        Iterator<Resource> itr = children.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
          Resource item = itr.next();
          Tag tag = item.adaptTo(Tag.class);
          if (tag != null) {           
            Iterator<Tag> childitr = tag.listAllSubTags();
            while (childitr.hasNext()) {
              Tag childitem = childitr.next();
              myHashMap.put((String)tag.getName, ((String)childitem.getName());
            }
          }
        }
      }   
      session.logout();  
      return myHashMap;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And the code in the crx as follows

```js
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*, com.day.cq.tagging.* " %>
<%@page import="com.aem.community.core.services.*" %>
<%@page import="com.aem.community.core.services.Impl.*" %>
<% 
try {    
  com.aem.community.core.services.ListTags taglist = sling.getService(com.aem.community.core.services.ListTags.class);

  Map tagnames = taglist.listAllTags(); 
  out.print(tagnames);
} catch(Exception e) {
  out.print(e);
}
%>
```

But I am unable to fetch the values returned in the map by the service to the jsp of the component. I am getting a  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise to learn the APIs or are you trying to meet some business requirement? If the latter is the case, there are probably better ways of obtaining a list of tags. Frankly, I'm not sure why you would do that at all.

Comment: Also: Would you mind sharing the stacktrace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: A couple pointers: 1) use the TagManager API  2) avoid JSP scriptlets. More info: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/TagManager.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to inject ResourceResolver to OSGI Service. You can't do this:

```
@Reference
private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;
```

Probably it's throwing NullPointerException where you use the resource resolver. There are couple of ways to get resource resolver in OSGI service but you can refer to http://www.one-inside.com/aem6-1-resourceresolver-access-in-services/ or http://scrupulo.com/posts/blog/view/5-tips-on-the-sling-resource-resolver

Answer (score 0):

This answer to help others who are looking for an efficient of traversing resource trees rather than writing multiple loops and debugging them.
Sling API provides and abstract implementation called the AbstractResourceVisitor.html ([AbstractResourceVisitor](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/AbstractResourceVisitor.html))
and ACS commons provides a sample implementation.[Sample Implementation](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/resources/SampleResourceVisitor.java)

TLDR : Implement a concrete class which extends the AbstractResourceVisitor Override the visit method with the operation that needs to be performed.You can also override the accept methods if there is a custom condition that is to be considered while continuing traversal.